# Print JSON response instead of response code

Tags: python, json, rest, parsing

How do I get the JSON response from this, when I print the `response` I just get the response status of 200 instead of the JSON tree.

```
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456789',
}

params = (
    ('interval', 'month'),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.peakon.com/v1/engagement/overview', headers=headers, params=params)

print(response)
```

Comment: `response.json()`?

Comment: For future reference, the inbuilt python function 'dir()' returns a list of the attributes of an object,

So in this case using dir(response) would return a list of all the methods you can call on 'response' including json, which is the one you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(response.json())` should give the the data formatted as JSON for this response.